# Tensorflow neural network doesn't optimize properly

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am a beginner to neural networks and TensorFlow, I have tried the following code for handwritten digit classification (single layer perceptron model)

I have downloaded the dataset from kaggle which contains the first column as the digit and the next 784 columns the pixel values.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from PIL import Image

    tr = open("train.csv","r")

    tr_cont=tr.read()
    tr_cont=tr_cont.split("\n")
    tr_cont = tr_cont[1:]
    train_in=[]
    train_out=[]

    for inp in tr_cont:
        data = inp.split(",")
        num = [0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]   #to identify the digit

        num[int(data[0])] = 1   #data[0] is the digit label
        train_out.append(num)
        train_in.append(data[1:])   #these are the pixel values

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 784])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 10])

    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,10])) #weights
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))  #biases

    output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b))

    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(output-y))

    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3)
    train_m = opt.minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(train_m , {x : train_in , y : train_out})
        cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x : train_in , y : train_out})
        print(i,"  ",cost)
```

Output always shows:

0    42000.0

1    42000.0

2    42000.0

3    42000.0

4    42000.0

5    42000.0

6    42000.0

7    42000.0

8    42000.0

9    42000.0

10    42000.0

.
   .
   .
  etc

So, I assume that the neural networks aren't working.

I have tried learning rates 0.01, 0.2, 0.3, but it shows the same output.

What's wrong here?

Should I add hidden layers?

EDIT:
I have also tried to get the output for test samples. It shows the same output for every test sample:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Did you normalize pixel values?

Comment: Yeah thanks, it works now

Comment: Can you accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused, because pixel values was not normalized. Normalization is appropriate because optimization algorithms works better if inputs are from some appropriate range 0-1 for example. For pixel values is enough division by 255.